# Internet Explorer, How to change iframes src

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

For some reasons I'm using an Iframe to display googlemaps, when I want to change it's content I'm just changing the Iframe src using JQuery.

$('#ggMap').attr('src', 'http://newurl.com');

Apparently it's not doing anything on Internet Explorer.

Does anyone know how I could do the same thing with IE?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the src of an IFrame with javascript, so I guess there is a script error preventing IE from working properly.

Have you debugged the script?

Comment: not sure why this would be checked as a solution. Changing the src with javascript just doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about jQuery, but regular javascript would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('ggMap').src = 'http://newurl.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had the same problem with IE8 and changing the src via jQuery/JS didn't work like this. What I now do is actually use `jQuery.clone()` to clone the iframe, then change it's src, then remove the original iframe and insert the clone...